# Python Turtle: Draw concentric circles using circle() method

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I was showing a grandson patterns drawn with Python's Turtle module,
and he asked to see concentric circles.
I thought it would be faster to use the turtle's [`circle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) to draw them
than to write my own code for generating a circle. Ha! I am stuck. 
I see that the circle produced begins its circumference at the turtle's
current location and its direction of drawing depends on turtle's current
direction of motion, but I can't figure out what I need to do to get
concentric circles.
I am not at this point interested in an efficient way of producing
concentric circles: I want to see what I have to do to get
*this* way to work:

```
def turtle_pos(art,posxy,lift):
    if lift:
        art.penup()
        art.setposition(posxy)
        art.pendown()

def drawit(tshape,tcolor,pen_color,pen_thick,scolor,radius,mv):
    window=turtle.Screen() #Request a screen
    window.bgcolor(scolor) #Set its color

    #...code that defines the turtle trl

    for j in range(1,11):
        turtle_pos(trl,[trl.xcor()+mv,trl.ycor()-mv],1)
        trl.circle(j*radius)

drawit("turtle","purple","green",4,"black",20,30)
```

Comment: Could you post your current code?

Comment: def turtle_pos(art,posxy,lift):
  if  lift: art.penup()
  art.setposition(posxy)
  art.pendown()

def drawit(tshape,tcolor,pen_color,pen_thick,scolor,radius,mv):
  window=turtle.Screen()        #Request a screen
  window.bgcolor(scolor)        #Set its color
  
  #…code that defines the turtle trl
  for j in range(1,11):
    turtle_pos(trl,[trl.xcor()+mv,trl.ycor()-mv],1)
    trl.circle(j*radius)
    

drawit("turtle","purple","green",4,"black",20,30) -- sorry, don't know how to format it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import turtle

turtle.penup()
for i in range(1, 500, 50):
    turtle.right(90)    # Face South
    turtle.forward(i)   # Move one radius
    turtle.right(270)   # Back to start heading
    turtle.pendown()    # Put the pen back down
    turtle.circle(i)    # Draw a circle
    turtle.penup()      # Pen up while we go home
    turtle.home()       # Head back to the start pos
```

Which creates the picture below:

[image]

Basically it moves the turtle down one radius lenght to keep the center point for all the circles in the same spot.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> The center is radius units left of the turtle.

So wherever the turtle is when you start to draw a circle, the center of that circle is some distance to the right. After each circle, just move left or right some number of pixels and draw another circle whose radius is adjusted for the distance the turtle moved. For example, if you draw a circle with a radius of 50 pixels, then move right 10 pixels, you would draw another circle with a radius of 40, and the two circles should be concentric.

Comment: Under the current Python turtle, this answer no longer appears to be valid.  The documentation quoted is still the same but it's bogus as the location of the center relative to the turtle depends on the turtle's heading.  With the default initial heading, the quote is simply wrong.  Switching to 'logo' mode, it would be valid for just the initial heading.  But your specific example is currently wrong as you'd have to move the opposite way to make the circles concentric.  And it wouldn't work for any other heading.

Answer (score 0):

So now i am giving you the exact code that can draw concentric circles.

```
import turtle
t=turtle.Turtle()
for i in range(5):
  t.circle(i*10)
  t.penup()
  t.setposition(0,-(i*10))
  t.pendown()
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not at this point interested in an efficient way of producing
>   concentric circles: I want to see what I have to do to get *this* way to
>   work

To address the OP's question, the change to their original code to make it work is trivial:

```
turtle_pos(trl, [trl.xcor() + mv, trl.ycor() - mv], 1)
trl.circle(j * radius)
```

becomes:

```
turtle_pos(trl, [trl.xcor(), trl.ycor() - mv], 1)
trl.circle(j * mv + radius)
```

The complete code with the above fix and some style changes:

```
import turtle

def turtle_pos(art, posxy, lift):
    if lift:
        art.penup()
        art.setposition(posxy)
        art.pendown()

def drawit(tshape, tcolor, pen_color, pen_thick, scolor, radius, mv):
    window = turtle.Screen()  # Request a screen
    window.bgcolor(scolor)  # Set its color

    #...code that defines the turtle trl
    trl = turtle.Turtle(tshape)
    trl.pencolor(pen_color)
    trl.fillcolor(tcolor)  # not filling but makes body of turtle this color
    trl.width(pen_thick)

    for j in range(10):
        turtle_pos(trl, (trl.xcor(), trl.ycor() - mv), True)
        trl.circle(j * mv + radius)

    window.mainloop()

drawit("turtle", "purple", "green", 4, "black", 20, 30)
```

[image]